# SQLAlchemy: How to reference a table mapping read-only?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With SQLAlchemy, I would like to use a first table with records/fields containing values that can be used as the legitimate values of a field in a second table.

However, the records of the first table should not be able to be changed from the field of the second table, only be referenced.

I have a database with two models in Sqlalchemy:

```py
class Country(Base):
__tablename__ = 'countries'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String, unique=True)
code = Column(String, unique=True)


class Address(Base):
__tablename__ = 'addresses'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
row_1 = Column(String)
row_2 = Column(String)
row_3 = Column(String)
row_4 = Column(String)
row_5 = Column(String)
country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('countries.id'))
country = relationship("Country")
```

I populate the database with the names and codes of the countries of the world using the country model. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2))

Now I instantiate an address object, `a1`, and assign a country object `c1` to it:

```py
a1.country = c1
```

This works; Now I can for instance do this:

```py
a1.country.name
>>> 'Iceland'
```

However, I can also do this:

```py
a1.country.name = 'Switzerland'
a1.country.name
>>> 'Switzerland'
```

This is not what I want. I want to be able to use countries from the database to assign to address objects and reference the country from the address object as well, but altering a country object should only be allowed by accessing a country object directly, for instance an isolated country object that is the result of a query to the database.

I want to use the Country mapping as a read-only reference containing allowed values for the country column of address.

How can I do this?

I tried the following inside the Address class definition:

```py
country = relationship("Country", viewonly=True)
```

However, when I create an address and assign a country object to it (by setting country_id of Address to id of Country) with the above viewonly relationship mapping and then change the name of the country object from the address object, I get the same behavior:

After committing the address object with the changed country name to the database and reading it back, the country name is altered (from the Address class object).

How should it be done?

Comment: [`viewonly`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.viewonly) makes the **relationship** viewonly, i.e. you shouldn't be able to do `a1.country = c1`. It does not disable tracking of changes to attributes of related objects, which should be obvious if you think about it a bit; `a1.country` just evaluates to the object.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks, I edited the question to reflect that when using viewonly=True, the country of Address must be set using Address.country_id instead. Any ideas on the problem making the object immutable when accessed as the Address property? What is the normal way to handle such a scenario? Using some other approach?